# Open two ports in the same computer. What would be the Mbps rate between them?

Tags: sockets, bandwidth

If I am opening two ports and connect them in localhost. (On the same computer) What would be the rate between them?

My internet's rate is 100 Mbps and network is 1Gbps.

Comment: @BrianAgnew Very old one, 2GB ram, Dual 1.8GHZ.

Comment: Depends very much on the network cards, and where you get the data from and what you do with it.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau On the same computer.

Comment: Ok, if you use localhost then the network is more or less not involved. You just shuffle data from your app to the system and back. Hard to say, but it has nothing to do with the 100 Mbps or 1Gbps. Try it! :)

Comment: You can use somehing like nuttcp to check but you'll be benchmarking RAM speed and the TCP stack. You can still get better performance with unix domain sockets or pipes if that's what you were wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data transfers are on the same machine, then your internet/network speed isn't relevant since data won't go through the network card.

The only thing that matters is your computer processing speed ;)

Comment: The data transfer would still go through the TCP/IP stack, so while the effective bandwidth would be very high, it would still be measurable.